Multimode squeezed operator
Given CCR (bosonic) algebra, with creation / annihilation operators $a_{i}^{\dagger}, a_i$ acting on a single particle Hilbert space $\mathbb{h}$, let's introduce the multimode squeezed operator for $N$ modes $S_N$ defined as follows:
$$S_N = e^{\frac{1}{2} (\sum_{i,j = 1}^{N} U_{i,j}^{N} a_{i}^{\dagger}a_{j}^{\dagger} - U_{i,j}^{N} a_{i}a_{j})}\quad ,$$
where the $N\times N$ matrix $U_N = (U_{i,j}^{N})$ is, for simplicity, supposed to be real and symmetric.
Question: are known the necessary and sufficient conditions on the matrix $U_N$ such that the operator limit $S_N \to S$ converges in operator norm topology to a certain $S$?
